# How can I select the value of an html select that was dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have two placeholders for two different html selects that will be created dynamically

```
var dropdown1 = '#select1';
var dropdown2 = '#select2';
```

at a later moment in time I dynamically create the elements and attach an event...

```
$('some div').append(dropdown1);
$('some div').append(dropdown2);
$(dropdown1).append('<option>' + value + '</option>'); 
$(dropdown1).append('<option>' + value + '</option>');
```

then I add an event listener...

```
$(document.body).on('change', dropdown1, function() {
alert($(dropdown1).val());
alert($(dropdown2).val());

});
```

I want to be able to get the value of both dropdown 1 AND dropdown 2. Instead I get an empty array or undefined.

Anyone has any idea how I can get both values for these dynamically created selects ?

Comment: `$('some div').append(dropdown1)` obviously isn't the code you use to create the select element given that `dropdown1` contains the string `'#select1'` rather than html for a select element. Also you're missing quotes on the last part of `$(dropdown1).append('<option>' + value + </option>);`. Please show your _actual_ code, and consider setting up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: should be `alert($(dropdown1).val());` ?

Comment: There's a lot of mistakes with this piece of code; bad selectors, appending string literals (where the intention appears to be elements)... granted it may be dummy code, but please make sure it is concrete and working, because there are more issues than what you are asking. I suggest jsFiddle

Comment: _"just a stub... please don't focus on this... I have correctly placed a select and options"_ - OK, so from the small amount of information you've given us `$(dropdown1).val()` _will_ work _if_ `dropdown1` holds a string `'#select1'` _and_ there is exactly one element with that id at the time that line runs. What does `$(dropdown1).length` give you at that same point in the code? If everything else is right as you claim, it should be `1`. For further help, please show your real code and set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not holding a reference to a jQuery object, just a string of the id. Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', dropdown1, function() {
    alert($(dropdown1).val()); /* or, you could use $(this).val() */
    alert($(dropdown2).val());    
});
```

This will only fire when you change the first drop down because of the selector parameter passed to on().